# Return reference to a generic list?

Tags: c#, list, pass-by-reference

Suppose I have classes set up like this:

```
public abstract class GenericCustomerInformation
{
    //abstract methods declared here
}

public class Emails : GenericCustomerInformation
{
    //some new stuff, and also overriding methods from GenericCustomerInformation
}

public class PhoneNumber : GenericCustomerInformation
{
    //some new stuff, and also overriding methods from GenericCustomerInformation
}

//and more derivative classes for emails, addresses, etc ..
```

Then I have this function to return a specific list:

```
public List<GenericCustomerInformation> GetLists<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Alias))
    {
        return aliases.Cast<GenericCustomerInformation>().ToList();
    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(PhoneNumber))
    {
        return phoneNumbers.Cast<GenericCustomerInformation>().ToList();
    }
    // .. and the same for emails, addresses, etc ..
}
```

Now suppose I want to add to these lists using just one function:

```
public void AddToList<T>(T iGenericCustomerInformation)
{
    GetLists<T>().Add((T)(object)iGenericCustomerInformation); //Doesn't work as intended. GetLists<T> seems to be returning lists as value, which is why any additions 
}
```

The problem is that `AddToList<T>` doesn't work as intended. `GetLists<T>` seems to be returning lists as value, which is why any additions I do are not reflected in the primary list structure ...

So how to return the list as a reference, so that I can use that reference to do list additions through other functions ?

Comment: `GetLists()` isn't returning the lists by value. What's happening is that `aliases.Cast<GenericCustomerInformation>().ToList();` is creating a completely new list.

Comment: All classes and interfaces are reference types.

Comment: @JLRishe, I see the problem .. Any solution to that which doesn't involve code redundancy ?

Answer (score 1):

You're already defeating the point of generics by having all those `typeof()`s and `if` statements. That's not generic at all. I'd say just put the `if` statement in your `AddToList()` method and nix the generics.

```
public void AddToList(GenericCustomerInformation item)
{
    Alias aliasItem = item as Alias;
    if(aliasItem != null)
    {
        aliases.Add(aliasItem);
        return;
    }

    PhoneNumber phoneNumberItem = item as PhoneNumber;
    if(phoneNumberItem != null) 
    {
         phoneNumbers.Add(phoneNumberItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep all your lists in a dictionary of lists ?

```
private Dictionary<Type, List<GenericCustomerInformation>> MyLists;

public List<GenericCustomerInformation> GetLists<T>()
{
    return MyLists[typeof(T)];
}

public void AddToLists<T>(GenericCustomerInformation item)
{
    GetLists<T>().Add(item);
}
```